# Парсинг файла Word (*.docx) средствами C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ms-word

стоит задача парсинга текста из документа *.docx. Какие есть инструменты для этого в С++?

Я пробовала:
библиотеку DuckX, но она склеивает фрагменты текста. Как я поняла, дело в том, что она не предназначена для работы с расширенной таблицей символов;

Изучить подробнее, как использовать OpenXml SDK для MVS2015, но информации очень мало, все примеры на сайте Microsoft для C#. Работает ли это для C++? Как подключить и использовать?;

Видела, что можно каким-то образом подключить необходимые функции с помощью, например, #import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSWORD.OLB", но такое решение требует указать путь, который на разных ПК может быть разным, поэтому это не подходит.

Comment: Используйте OpenXml SDK, да он на C#.

Comment: @user7860670 мне вот интересно как вы оцениваете помощь от вашего комментария? человек явно указал что задача стоит на C++ и то что он знает про решение на C#, в чём смысл вашего сообщения?

Answer (score -1):

Лучше используйте для этих целей Office Interop библиотеки и средства VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) на C#, с помощью C++ работать с оффисными документами крайне не удобно. На VSTO полная свобода действий..